# Printing XML elements by specifying its attribute

Tags: java, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dwml version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.nws.noaa.gov/forecasts/xml/DWMLgen/schema/DWML.xsd">
  <head>
    <product srsName="WGS 1984" concise-name="time-series" operational-mode="official">
      <title>NOAA's National Weather Service Forecast Data</title>
      <field>meteorological</field>
      <category>forecast</category>
      <creation-date refresh-frequency="PT1H">2013-10-29T16:59:47Z</creation-date>
    </product>
    <source>
      <more-information>http://www.nws.noaa.gov/forecasts/xml/</more-information>
      <production-center>Meteorological Development Laboratory<sub-center>Product Generation Branch</sub-center></production-center>
      <disclaimer>http://www.nws.noaa.gov/disclaimer.html</disclaimer>
      <credit>http://www.weather.gov/</credit>
      <credit-logo>http://www.weather.gov/images/xml_logo.gif</credit-logo>
      <feedback>http://www.weather.gov/feedback.php</feedback>
    </source>
  </head>
  <data>
    <location>
      <location-key>point1</location-key>
      <point latitude="39.95" longitude="-75.17"/>
    </location>
    <moreWeatherInformation applicable-location="point1">http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?textField1=39.95&amp;textField2=-75.17</moreWeatherInformation>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
      <layout-key>k-p24h-n1-1</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time>2013-10-30T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2013-10-30T20:00:00-04:00</end-valid-time>
    </time-layout>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
      <layout-key>k-p24h-n2-2</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time>2013-10-29T20:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2013-10-30T09:00:00-04:00</end-valid-time>
      <start-valid-time>2013-10-30T20:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2013-10-31T09:00:00-04:00</end-valid-time>
    </time-layout>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none"> 
      <layout-key>k-p3h-n9-3</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time>2013-10-30T02:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
      <start-valid-time>2013-10-30T05:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
      <start-valid-time>2013-10-30T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
      <start-valid-time>2013-10-30T11:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
      <start-valid-time>2013-10-30T14:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
      <start-valid-time>2013-10-30T17:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
      <start-valid-time>2013-10-30T20:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
      <start-valid-time>2013-10-30T23:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
      <start-valid-time>2013-10-31T02:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
    </time-layout>
    <parameters applicable-location="point1">
      <temperature type="maximum" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p24h-n1-1">
        <name>Daily Maximum Temperature</name>
        <value>64</value>
      </temperature>
      <temperature type="minimum" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p24h-n2-2">
        <name>Daily Minimum Temperature</name>
        <value>44</value>
        <value>52</value>
      </temperature>
      <temperature type="hourly" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p3h-n9-3">
        <name>Temperature</name>
        <value>48</value>
        <value>48</value>
        <value>49</value>
        <value>57</value>
        <value>63</value>
        <value>62</value>
        <value>58</value>
        <value>56</value>
        <value>55</value>
      </temperature>
      <temperature type="dew point" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p3h-n9-3">
        <name>Dew Point Temperature</name>
        <value>40</value>
        <value>43</value>
        <value>45</value>
        <value>46</value>
        <value>47</value>
        <value>48</value>
        <value>49</value>
        <value>48</value>
        <value>47</value>
      </temperature>
      <wind-speed type="sustained" units="knots" time-layout="k-p3h-n9-3">
        <name>Wind Speed</name>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>2</value>
        <value>4</value>
        <value>6</value>
        <value>3</value>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>2</value>
      </wind-speed>
      <humidity type="relative" units="percent" time-layout="k-p3h-n9-3">
        <name>Relative Humidity</name>
        <value>74</value>
        <value>83</value>
        <value>86</value>
        <value>67</value>
        <value>56</value>
        <value>60</value>
        <value>72</value>
        <value>74</value>
        <value>74</value>
      </humidity>
    </parameters>
  </data>
</dwml>
```

Currently I am parsing this XML using `DocumentBuilder`, and I am printing this data rather rudimentarily, that is, I am parsing it like this:

```
 eElement.getElementsByTagName("temperature").item(2).getTextContent();
```

What that does is I am getting the element by the tag name `temperature`, the third item (`item(2)`), and getting the text content that way. However, I am interested in getting the content by specifying the attribute, and that is, through the `type`.

Is there anyway to display the content of this XML data through specifying the `type`? By specifying the `type` as `hourly`, and printing all contents under `<name>Temperature</name>`.

A psuedocode of how that would work is:

```
if(attributeType()==hourly){
    print all values of hourly temperature
}
```

Thank you

Comment: So you want to print all the value tag values

Comment: Yes, that is right, I would like to log those hourly values into a .csv file, but based on its `type`. In this context, the `type` here is `hourly`, but that is only a small example. I also have things like `wind-speed`, `dew-point`, etc.

Comment: Why I want to do this instead of hardcoding it based on the `item(i)` is because sometimes there may not be data on these specific parameters. If that data is missing, the hardcoded script would break, since something is missing (it would return errors). If I can have the code tell me that, for example, `type="hourly"` is missing data, that would negate the errors.

Comment: I would like to do it in Java, not Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use XPath for this sort of thing. It's just so much easier to work with.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(XML_FILE_URI);

XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/temperature[@type='hourly']/value/text()");

NodeList result = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < result.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(result.item(i).getNodeValue());
}
```

Comment: Hi @Chill. I have tried your way - it doesn't work, but that's probably because the path is not complete. I have pasted my entire XML document in my original post - could you give me a short tutorial on how to implement the path? I think we would need to do something like `data/temperature[@type='hourly']/value/text()`

Comment: You can even do `//temperature[@type='hourly']/value/text()`. There's lots of good tutorials on XPath out there if you google them (W3Schools was good enough for me to get a basic understanding). To explain this particular XPath: `//` (which I think you arelady figured out) means that the next element is any number of levels down the current subtree. So starting with `//temperature` means that you will find all temperature nodes in the tree. Square brackets mean to filter based on a condition for the node, so `[@type='hourly']` means to keep only temperature nodes with an attribute type=hourly

Comment: Then you want all `value` nodes underneath the temperature nodes (thus `/value`) and all of their text contents: `/text()`. Note that if there were two temperature nodes with a type = hourly, you would get all of their values in a single result set. That's because XPath tries to match all the nodes that match the path.

Comment: The path I used now is `/dwml/data/parameters/temperature[@type='dew point']/value/text()`. It works. Thanks so much for the suggestions! This is much more intuitive than using my old DOM method.

Comment: Is it also possible to specify where the element is == to? For example, where the `<name>` is equal to `Temperature`. I tried `/dwml/data/parameters/temperature[@type='hourly']/name[@'Temperature']/text()`

Comment: Yes, but you really will need to study XPath to understand this kind of thing (not that experimentation is a bad thing). In this specific case: `/dwml/data/parameters/temperature[@type='hourly' and name/text() = 'Temperature']/value/text()` should work. @ symbols are used for attributes, not tag names.

Comment: One thing to note is that if something isn't in the square brackets, that means it is part of the path to your result set. So having `/name` like you posted above, means that you aren't selecting the value nodes and would only be able to select children of the name node.

Comment: Wow - thanks Chill for the help! I'll try not to pester you again when I run into issues. What are some good beginner guides for XPath?